# Script to copy, transpose then paste values into another sheet, and then when next run to do the same, into the next available rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy, transpose, paste

I am trying to write a script that will move data from one sheet to another and simultaneously transpose it. I need to use the same script on the same Input Range several times (with different data), so it needs to paste each set of data in the next available set of rows in the destination sheet.

I have looked extensively on the site for solutions, but I have only been able to find solutions for each of these functions separately. (Copy and Paste, Transpose, Only paste in next empty row, and date Timestamp)

The only code I have been working on if from the first of those, and is as follows;

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var source = ss.getRange("Import!E4:I41");
 var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Database!E3:AP7");

 destSheet.appendRow(source.getValues()[0]);
 var destination = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow(), 1); // Added
 source.copyTo(destination, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES) // Added
}
```

---

Happy to learn more and have any feedback from people who know better.

[Example Sheet, with Ideal Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16u9GidufC4UZd0f3u_gNSlpY5xkrWJst5oReuxCNxQw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could see your sample Spreadsheet. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about what you want to do from your Spreadsheet. I apologize for this. Where can I see the sample input and output situation you expect?

Comment: I have highlighted the Input in Green, and Output in Yellow. I want to move the data from Sheet 'Import' to the selected rows in Sheet 'Database'. And then the subsequent rows below when I use the script next with different data.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your sample Spreadsheet, you want to convert from "Importer!E4:I41" to "Database!E3:AP7". Is my understanding correct? By the way, what is `NEXT TIME I USE THE SCRIPT, THE DATA NEEDS TO GO IN THESE ROWS` and `and then in here etc`?

Comment: Yes that is correct. However additionally after those cells have been filled I need it script to paste into the next data 5 rows down (E8:AP12), and then next time 5 down again, and so on. The text you are asking about was an example of me showing where the next set needs to go.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor understanding. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about your goal. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand about your question, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: Apologies, it is a tough problem to describe; I need Importer!E4:I41 to be scripted automatically to transpose into Database!E3:AP7. I then will manually clear Importer Selection, add my new data manually, then run script again to transpose to Database!E8:AP12. And so on, down the Database.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot see the vision of your replying. I apologize for my poor English skill.